# Getting only partial output

Tags: c++, c++11

I wrote a C++ program to print out the multiplication of all two digit numbers.
I am getting only partial output of some product and not the entire output.
Code:

```
int main()
{
    int ans;
    for (int i = 10; i <= 99; i++) {
        for (int j = 10; j <= 99; j++) {
            ans = i * j;
            cout << ans << endl;
        }
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The output starts from `6816` (instead of `10*10=100`) upto `9801` (which is `99*99`).

On the other hand if I do the same for single digits, the output is correct.

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vPv0xB9CF3sHHkWW). Try increasing the buffer size of your terminal software or use redirect to write the output to a file.

Comment: May be your need to simply increase the console window size. There is no problem with the code.

Comment: @AkhileshChobey: can you please click on the grey check mark below the answer score of one of the answers to mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 3):

There are 299 numbers between `6801` and `9899` (both inclusive) printed from this program, so it seems you are using Command Prompt of Windows to view the result.

If so, to view all numbers in the window,

1. Right-click the window icon in upper left
2. Select "property"
3. Select "layout" tab
4. Set "height" in "buffer size of screen" to a large number such as "9999".

(The name of menus might not be correct because I am using Japanese OS)

[image: the menu]

Alternatively, you might want to use redirect to put the output into a text file.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Yes that worked. I tried in an online compiler so that worked over there. I thought the cin.get() was causing it. Thanks anyways

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why an Asian version of windows as example SC?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from missing `#include` and `using namespace std;` lines you did not post, there is nothing wrong with your program.

The output is 8100 lines long, are you sure you can see all these lines in your terminal?  Try redirecting the output to a file and load this file into an editor to verify the number of lines.